# Alternate colour between div using css

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want the alternating EditFormClass div to have a blue colour but this isn't working. I even tried `.EditFormClass:nth-child(3n)` but it didn't work. I guess the issue is because of the col-xs-6 div in between. How do I get this working?

Please help!

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/4kpz876e/

CSS:

```
.EditFormClass:nth-child(odd) {
    color: blue;
}
```

PHP Code

```
    <div class="row">
        <?php foreach ($this->fields as $field) { ?>
            <div class="col-xs-5 EditFormClass">
                <?php echo $field[0]; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <?php echo $field[1]; ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: `.EditFormClass:nth-child(2n) {` not working for you?

Comment: I tried this too. There's nothing for `.EditFormClass:nth-child(2n)` sadly. I believe it goes for the col-xs-6 div

Comment: could you please give us a fiddle / snippet so that we can check?

Comment: Added. This is what the php script generates currently. I want the entire `aaa x class` column to be in blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.col-xs-3:nth-child(4n-1)` for that:

```
.col-xs-3:nth-child(4n-1) {
    color: blue;
}
```

Check here:
https://jsfiddle.net/yhvbLgun/

## The explanation

In each row you have 4 child-divs, and you want the 3rd of them to have the blue color, so apply the blue color to the 4th-1 child div (using `:nth-child(4n-1)`).

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this

```
.EditFormClass:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. Added the JSFIDDLE. It is what the php script generates currently. I want the entire `aaa 1 class`, `aaa 1 class`, to `aaa 77 class`,  column to be in blue.